# Teradata locks - How to know if a table is locked?

Tags: sql, locking, teradata

Is there a way to know if a table is locked and what kind of lock is currently on a table? I was hoping for something through the DBC tables in teradata, but I can't find any reference to anything like this. I have normal user access and the DBA is no help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK only DBA utilities are available to determine the type of lock on a table.

With only user-level rights you can do something like the following (from [here](http://www.teradataforum.com/teradata/20090330_142344.htm)):

```
Lock Table dbName.myTable for Access nowait
Select * from dbName.myTable;
```

And according to the master himself (Geoffrey Rommel):

> If the table is locked, you will get
>   error 7423, "Object already locked and
>   NOWAIT. Transaction Aborted."

Comment: I would think you have to use FOR WRITE instead of FOR ACCESS, since FOR ACCESS will succeed even if the table is locked for write.

Comment: This may be getting into the nit picky area, but if you are concerned about performance, you might want to replace the * with (top 1 1). It will prevent a full table retrieval from happening.

Comment: What happens as result of above SQL if the table is NOT locked? Does it get locked? If YES then how to ensure it gets unlocked?

Comment: i no longer work with a Teradata DB; however, 1) i presume you get a notification that the lock was enforced, and 2) i found this: "If you ROLLBACK / ABORT or COMMIT the transaction, then the locks are released. And in Teradata mode, a database error causes an automatic rollback before returning the error status to the client." --from https://downloads.teradata.com/forum/analytics/release-lock-from-a-table